# material-ui checkbox with react-hook-form

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I can't set the value of a material-ui checkbox programmatically using react-hook-form `reset` method

Here there is an example of my code, as you can note, `TextField` works correctly, `CheckBox` doesn't!

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shamir-8lqph?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

According to the [controller example](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/app/src/controller.tsx) and [the doc](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/), you can use `Controller` from `react-hook-form` to change the value of material UI checkboxes properly. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-pine-6gsh1?file=/src/App.js:151-166)

first checkbox (without label) would be as below:

```
<Controller
          name="checkwithoutlabel"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={false}
          rules={{ required: true }}
          render={(props) => (
            <Checkbox
              onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.checked)}
              checked={props.value}
            /> 
          )}
/>
```

And the `FormControlLabel` component should be written like:

```
<FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Controller
              name={"checkwithlabel"}
              control={control}
              defaultValue={false}
              render={(props) => (
                <Checkbox
                  {...props}
                  checked={props.value}
                  onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.checked)}
                />
              )}
            />
          }
          label={"Checkbox with label"}
        />
```