# Material-UI checkbox with react-hook-form V7 won't sent correct value when the cheked value is changed via logic

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form V7.14.2 and I'm using a Material-UI checkbox that can be checked by the user manually or will be automatically checked depending on the values of certain inputs.
This is working OK.

The issue is that when submitting the form, if the check box was checked via logic, depending on the values of certain input, the value sent to the back end will be false.
If the user manually checks the check box, then it will send the correct value. -True if checked-.

I read the documentation to migrate from V6 to V7 in react-hook-form page, as I was previously using V6 and the code works there.
https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/

I also read some previous answers in Stackoverflow such as this one: [material-ui checkbox with react-hook-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66453383/material-ui-checkbox-with-react-hook-form) but with no success.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCheckCircle } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { Controller, set } from "react-hook-form";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { DarkThemeContext } from "../../context/DarkThemeContext";
import { useStylesSelectPropDetails } from "../../styledComponent/SelectPropDetailsStyled";
import { IMAGES_LINK } from "../../api/doFetch";

const useStylesLabel = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  label: {
    fontSize: "1em",
    fontFamily: "Open Sans Hebrew, sans-serif !important",
    fontWeight: 400,
    lineHeight: 1.5,
  },
}));

const CheckboxPropDetails = ({
  register,
  name,
  label,
  checked,
  isShelter,
  isElevator,
}) => {
  const classesLabel = useStylesLabel();
  const [isDarkTheme] = useContext(DarkThemeContext);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const props = { isDarkTheme: isDarkTheme };
  const classes = useStylesSelectPropDetails(props);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setIsChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (name === "shelter") {
      if (  isShelter,) {
        setIsChecked(true);
      } else setIsChecked(false);
    }
    if (name === "elevator") {
      console.log("elevator");

      if (isElevator) {
        console.log("isElevator", isElevator);
        setIsChecked(true);
      } else setIsChecked(false);
    }
  }, [  isShelter, isElevator]);

  return (
    <>
      <FormControlLabel
        classes={classesLabel}
        control={
          <Checkbox
            name={name}
            id={name}
            defaultChecked={checked ? checked : false}
            {...register(name)}
            color="primary"
            size={"medium"}
            icon={
              <img
                src={`${IMAGES_LINK}/dashboard/elements/rec.svg`}
                alt="Circle"
                style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
              />
            }
            disableRipple
            checkedIcon={
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faCheckCircle}
                style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
              />
            }
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          />
        }
        labelPlacement="end"
        label={<p className={classes.paragraphAddProp}>{label}</p>}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Code used with V6 on react-hook-form:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCheckCircle } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { DarkThemeContext } from "../../context/DarkThemeContext";
import { useStylesSelectPropDetails } from "../../styledComponent/SelectPropDetailsStyled";
import { IMAGES_LINK } from "../../api/doFetch";

const useStylesLabel = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  label: {
    fontSize: "1em",
    fontFamily: "Open Sans Hebrew, sans-serif !important",
    fontWeight: 400,
    lineHeight: 1.5,
  },
}));

const CheckboxPropDetails = ({
  register,
  name,
  label,
  checked,
  isShelter,
  isElevator,
}) => {
  const classesLabel = useStylesLabel();
  const [isDarkTheme] = useContext(DarkThemeContext);
  const props = { isDarkTheme: isDarkTheme };
  const classes = useStylesSelectPropDetails(props);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("event", event.target.checked);
    setIsChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (name === "shelter") {
      if (isShelter) {
        setIsChecked(true);
      } else setIsChecked(false);
    }
    if (name === "elevator") {   
      if (isElevator) {
           setIsChecked(true);
      } else setIsChecked(false);
    }
  }, [isShelter, isElevator]);

  return (
    <>
      <FormControlLabel
        classes={classesLabel}
        control={
          <Checkbox
            name={name}
            defaultChecked={checked ? checked : false}
            inputRef={register}
            color="primary"
            size={"medium"}
            icon={
              <img
                src={`${IMAGES_LINK}/dashboard/elements/rec.svg`}
                alt="Circle"
                style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
              />
            }
            disableRipple
            checkedIcon={
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faCheckCircle}
                style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
              />
            }
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          />
        }
        labelPlacement="end"
        label={<p className={classes.paragraphAddProp}>{label}</p>}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Control, register, and so are being pass as props from another component.

As mention before, it's working on V6.
The difference in V6 and V7 is one line:

in V6

```
  inputRef={register}
```

in V7

```
  {...register(name)}
```

How could I make it so that when the checked value is change via logic that it will register and on submit will be send to the backend as true?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MUI `<Checkbox />` component has a slighty different interface for setting a `value`. The RHF value has to be set with `checked` prop.

In v6 you just passed `register` to the `inputRef`, but since v7 calling `register` will return an object - two properties of this object are `value` and `onChange`. So when spreading your `register` call to the MUI `<Checkbox />` you're setting the link for the actual value to the `value` prop instead of using the `checked` prop.

You should therefore use RHF's `<Controller />` component, check the docs [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs) for more infos about integrating external controlled components.

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Controller
      name="checkbox"
      control={control}
      defaultValue={false}
      render={({ field: { value, ref, ...field } }) => (
        <Checkbox
          {...field}
          inputRef={ref}
          checked={!!value}
          color="primary"
          size={"medium"}
          disableRipple
        />
      )}
    />
  }
  label="Checkbox"
  labelPlacement="end"
/>
```

One important note: you have to set the value with `checked={!!value}` to avoid a warning about changing a component from uncontrolled to controlled in case that your `defaultValue` for `someCheckbox` is initially `undefined`.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: knoefel, thank you for your answer.
I did some tests with some changes to adapt the CodeSandbox to my needs.
Still not working.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-basic-forked-2ucim?file=/src/index.js.
Here you'll notice I added some code to automatically change the checked value depending on the value of a variable, but when submitting, even if the checkbox is checked the value is 0.
Thanks again for your help

Comment: The problem is you're not updating RHF's state for the "checkbox" field, when setting the `checked` prop like you do. So RHF's state for the "checkbox" field will always stay `false`. To update the field state outside of the `<Controller />` for a specific field you have to use RHF's `setValue`. So there's no need for `useState` here - check this updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-basic-forked-szpwo?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Thanks again for your help knoefel. I'll check this on wednesday. Can't before. Will let you know my results

Comment: knoefel, thanks for your help.
It works.